# How to pass arguments in push+ret method?

Tags: assembly, call

If I use `call`,

```
push b
push a
call address
```

is valid but using `call` makes me confusing with address.
So I want to use `push`+`ret` method like this:

```
push b
push a
push address
ret
```

But this time, passing arguments looks not working properly.
How can I pass address with this method?

Comment: I don't quite see why you would want to but if so then you will need to push a return address manually as well, otherwise the callee will try to return to `a`. Something along the lines of `push return_address` immediately prior to `push address` and a `return_address:` label wherever you want execution to continue.

Comment: What makes you think that the arguments aren't available on the stack?  You offer no justification of your belief.  Also, we really should have a Close option for, "The OP is trying to do something the wrong way."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> call address
> ```

This near call instruction does 2 things:

- It places on the stack the return address, which is the memory address directly after the `call address` instruction itself.
- It transfers control to the code at *address* by changing the `EIP` register.

Your replacement code **only** performs the latter operation.

To correct the code, push a return address manually:

```
    push b
    push a
    push Back
    push address
    ret
Back:
```

This time you'll see that passing the arguments works the same.

---

With this alternative method it's perfectly possible to place the *Back:* label anywhere you like **and where it makes sense!**